# Renaming a package

Tags: android

I would like to rename my application package from `com.hfad.prevencija` to `com.aaaa.prevencija`. How o achieve that?

[image: ge]

Answer (score 1):

1. In below screenshot, Suppose I want to change mygdx to someother name.

   [image]
2. Click on setting button which is showing in the corner of the screenshot and uncheck **Compact Middle Packages**

   [image]
3. Select mygdx and Refactor -> Rename -> Rename package -> Enter your desired name.

   [image]
4. Changed name will reflect in your **AndroidManifest** file, cross check once also check changes in **build.gradle** file